# Enable multicast querier by default for Linux bridge

Tags: linux, multicast

Does anyone know how to enable multicast querier by default for bridge?

For example, I have application it will create some bridges now. If I want to enable multicast querier on these bridges, I can update the file to 1 manually.

> echo "1" > /sys/devices/virtual/net/virbr0/bridge/multicast_querier

Is it possible to enable it by default? So that once create new bridge, the multicast querier is enabled.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I fix this problem by update the udev rules to enable this when create device.

```
# cat /etc/udev/rules.d/61-qbr-querier.rules
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", RUN+="/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/multicast_querier_enable"

# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/multicast_querier_enable
#!/bin/bash 

if [[ $INTERFACE == qbr* ]] 
then 
    echo 1 > /sys/class/net/$INTERFACE/bridge/multicast_querier 
fi
```